How to achieve High velocity in nav2
I want to achieve a high speed of 10 m/s for my robot using ROS2 Humble with Nav2. Currently, I'm using NavFn as the global planner and DWB as the local planner. How can I adjust these planners to support such high speeds? Are there specific configuration parameters I should focus on to ensure the robot can operate safely and effectively at this speed? Also if NavFn and DWB might not be optimized for high-speed navigation, are there alternative global and local planners in Nav2 that are better suited for achieving speeds of 10 m/s? What planners and controllers would you recommend for high-speed operation, and how should they be configured for optimal performance?

High Velocity is feasible you want to put into account these aspects
Faster robot means :

More stuff to process on the same CPU/GPU so check that CPU/GPU are
not throttling, else buy powerful hardware
Error related to hardware, physics and environment will raise. Consider buying better quality sensors and actuators (IMU,wheels, encoder , etc)

It is not the algorithm that will fail you most of the time, it will be the hardware, so check your hardware first then you can do 10 m/s.
For the software :
you can use theta star planner and you can not worry about the HW so start with a Gazebo Simulation at first.
Test your configurations extensively in a virtual environment before real-world implementation. This is crucial to ensure that your adjustments perform as expected without risking hardware.

"This planner could be used in scenarios where planning speed matters
"

https://index.ros.org/p/nav2_theta_star_planner/

Review the parameters available in the Nav2 docs: https://docs.nav2.org/

I tried to tune the parameters of NavFn and DWB but weird problems are coming. Can you tell me if achieving 10 m/s is possible or if a better controller and planner exists for this purpose?
